# AddFontMemResourceEx and D3DXCreateFont corruption

Tags: c++, directx, directx9, fonts

I'm trying to load a font from a buffer using [AddFontMemResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then creating a D3D font with [D3DXCreateFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb172773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This works fine on every platform except Windows XP, where it causes the wrong glyphs to be rendered.

Here's the relevant code (modified slightly for brevity):

```
char* fontName = "FontName";

HANDLE hFont = AddFontMemResourceEx(data, size, 0, &loaded);

if(!hFont || !loaded) {
    //error handling
}

HRESULT res = D3DXCreateFont(device, 30, 0, FW_NORMAL, 1, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
    ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, fontName, &font);

if(res != S_OK) {
    //error handling
}

...some code later...
//DrawTextA/W, makes no difference to the result
font->DrawTextW(NULL, message, -1, &rect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP, colour);
```

Here's an example render:
[image]

Interestingly, if I make a small change to the code to save the font to disk and then reload it with another API function, everything works fine:

```
char* fontName= "FontName";
char* fileName = "FontName.otf";

FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "w+b");
fwrite(data, size, 1, file);
fclose(file);

//non-ex version works fine too
AddFontResourceEx(fileName, FR_PRIVATE, 0);

HRESULT res = D3DXCreateFont(device, 30, 0, FW_NORMAL, 1, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
    ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, fontName, &font);

if(res != S_OK) {
    //error handling
}

...some code later...
//DrawTextA/W, makes no difference to the result
font->DrawTextW(NULL, message, -1, &rect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP, colour);
```

One caveat is that if the FR_NOT_ENUM flag is specified, even loading from file will result in the same problem. According to the documentation, this flag is implicitly set when using AddFontMemResourceEx.

> A font that is added by AddFontMemResourceEx is always private to the process that made the call and is not enumerable.

It seems this is possibly a bug in XP's API or just poor documentation that's leading to misuse (that happens to work on newer platforms).

Is there something I've missed?